# What is Megan-35 encryption?

Tags: encryption, decryption, algorithm

There are a lot of websites offering online Megan-35 encryption/decryption. Surprisingly, I haven't been able to spot out any resources detailing the underlying algorithm. Can anyone provide any link to the Megan-35 algorithm itself?

Answer (score 4):

The Megan-35 is an encoding and not and encryption.
It is a variant of the famous Base64.

The first step to encode to Megan-35 is to encode in base64. Then for each letter in base64 you will translate this letter to another letter.

You can find a python code on a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tunelko/49b7e64c1688d62d0ecd).

Comment: _[looked at the python code]_ What's the point? Is there any advantage gained by doing the character substitution?

Comment: No I don't see any advantages of this substitution.